# Unable to sideload iOS app on iPhone 7plus OSStatus error -2147416032

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, sideloading, osstatus

I am unable to sideload my app on my iPhone 7+.

ENV: Xcode 10.2.1,iPhone 7+ iOS:12.4, FREE Developer Account (I do not have a paid Developer Account)

> Errors (Targets->General->Signing):
>   - Operation couldn't be completed (OSStatus error -2147416032)
>   - No profiles for '' were found (Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching ''

**Here's what has been tried to troubleshoot the problem:**

1. Deleted existing Accounts setup under Xcode->Pref->Accounts
2. Deleted expired iPhone Developer Certificate from Key Access
3. Created a new Project, TestCodeSigning
4. During new Project creation, successfully added Team Account
5. Clicking Manage Certificates, 'No signing certificates' is displayed
6. Clicking 'iOS Development',causes error (OSStatus error -2147416032)

**I have already tried to no avail:**
1) Signing: Checking & Unchecking 'Automatically manage signing'
I had 3 other people try the same with their own iMacs, iPhone and their own Apple Free Developer accounts.  The outcome is exactly the same.

**Here are some of the questions I have:**

1. For learning purposes, why do the apps need signing (iOS Development Cert) when the app is only going to be installed on the personal iPhone
2. Another error I have encountered during application sideloading process is 'Provisioning Certificate is required....'.  Is the Provisioning certificate required for testing/learning?
3. For learning/testing purposes, is there anyway to completely disable code signing?
4. Shockingly Googling 'OSStatus error -2147416032' has not returned any results.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find the solution for this issue. I am also trying to get past this, I am not understanding what is causing the issues at all.